# R how to get one line of text from output

Tags: r, row, selection

I have the following in R: (myfile is the output)

```
>  Capital_Structure
       Total Debt to Total Equity  33.94
1     Total Debt to Total Capital  25.34
2      Total Debt to Total Assets  15.85
3               Interest Coverage  13.74
4        Long-Term Debt to Equity  32.71
5 Long-Term Debt to Total Capital  24.42
6         Long-Term Debt to Assets  0.15
```

Without writing that data to a file on my file-system and then importing the line from the file, I cannot figure out how to just assign the 33.94 (first number in the output) to some variable. I tried to use:

```
head(myfile, 0)
[1] Total Debt to Total Equity  33.94
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

but I don't want the second row of information which I assume is some stdio function. This seems a very simple thing to do but it has driven me crazy trying to work it out.

```
> dput(Capital_Structure)
structure(list(`Total Debt to Total Equity  33.94` = structure(c(6L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Interest Coverage  13.74", "Long-Term Debt to Assets  0.15", 
"Long-Term Debt to Equity  32.71", "Long-Term Debt to Total Capital  24.42", 
"Total Debt to Total Assets  15.85", "Total Debt to Total Capital  25.34"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Any help would be most welcome.
Regards
Stephen

Comment: Can you please share in your question the output of `dput(myfile)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what kind of object you are dealing with there, but it looks like:

- you had something like a csv with no headers
- you read this into R as a data.frame called `Capital_Structure`, but did so as if the first line of data had headers
- now you have a data.frame where 33.94 is being used as one of the column names.

If so, you can access these names using `names(Capital_Structure)` to get all names, and `names(Capital_Structure)[2]` to get just the second name, i.e. `33.94`

btw - R uses base 1, not base 0 -- so the second element is [2] and `head(foo, 0)` returns nothing

---

*EDIT* :

Now that you've provided a data excerpt, I can see that `Capital_Structure` is a data.frame with 6 rows and 1 column:

```
class(Capital_Structure) # what is it? a data.frame
dim(Capital_Structure) # how big? 6x1
```

If what you want is the "number after the last space", you can use greedy regex to remove everything before the last space:

```
gsub('^.* ', '', names(Capital_Structure))
[1] "33.94"
```

This will work for the other examples you put in the comments, too:

```
> gsub('^.* ', '', "P/E Ratio (TTM) 13.28")
[1] "13.28"
```

If you have a list of data.frames, and you want to get all the names, then apply this extraction function, you can use `lapply` and an anonymous function:

```
# example list; using data.table, bc base data.frame doesn't like spaces in names
library(data.table)
my_list <- list(data.table(`Total Debt to Total Equity  33.94`=1),
                data.table(`P/E Ratio (TTM) 13.28`=1))

# extract "thing after last space" from all names
lapply(my_list, function(x) gsub('^.* ', '', names(x)))
```

returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "33.94"

[[2]]
[1] "13.28"
```

Comment: ...or `names(myfile)[2]`. I can't quite tell what's what in your environment from the above

Comment: I am importing the data in from https://quotes.wsj.com/AU/XASX/RIO/FINANCIALS. I can see the data looks good as I have tried:
 fred = htmlParse(page), then 
tableNodes = getNodeSet(fred, "//table"), 
then when I look at tableNodes, I can see that tableNodes[[8]] has the correct information. I have a perfect XML table without all the other HTML code that "surrounds" the XML.
Also,  names(my.tables[[8]]) produces 
[1] "Total Debt to Total Equity  33.94"
and I cannot separate it due to different lengths. Eg, names(my.tables[[4]]) produces
[1] "P/E Ratio (TTM)  13.28"

Comment: I cant put the whole table in but it looks like:
> tableNodes[[8]]
<table class="cr_dataTable cr_sub_capital">
  <tr><td> <span class="data_lbl">Total Debt to Total Equity</span> ... </td> </tr>
  <tr><td> <span class="data_lbl">Total Debt to Total Capital</span> ... </td> </tr>
...
</table> 
This is just odd. Thanks to the suggestions so far.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your guidance arvi1000. I did what you suggested and it worked. The 33.94 that was presented was not a number but it could easily be changed into one. 
`
> mytemp
[1] "33.94"
> 
> is.numeric(mytemp)
[1] FALSE
> 
> mytemp1 <- as.numeric(as.character(mytemp))
> 
> is.numeric(mytemp1)
[1] TRUE`

I expect there is another way of getting that same result but it works for me.